# Rails - Class treated as Activerecord::Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a class `Meal` which as a relation with its `Type`
I created a scope
in the latter like :

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :meals
    scope :dessert, -> { where(name: "dessert") }
end
```

and in Meal i'm trying to get the meals that have a dessert Type:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :type
    scope :dessert, -> { joins(:type).merge(Type.dessert) }
end
```

When I just do `Type.dessert`, I get the right result
But when I type `Meal.dessert`, the console gives me this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `dessert' for ActiveRecord::Type:Module

For me, this error should at least say that Type is a Class as if I type an unexisting function:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `toto' for Type (call
>   'Type.connection' to establish a connection):Class

Can anyone help me to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say `::Type.dessert` to un-confuse Ruby.

But in my opinion you will save yourself a lot of trouble by renaming your model to `MealType`. Anyway "type" is so generic it is not a very helpful name. You will probably also wind up with `UserType`, `MenuType`, `RestaurantType`, `SubscriptionType`, and on and on. It is as bad as having a model named `Group`. . . .

Comment: Thanks, i had thought that this might me the cause of my problem, but i have a lot of code using this. I think i'll just accept my fate